# Explain analyze: Total time spent executing a task. Documentation error or my error?

Tags: postgresql, sql-execution-plan, explain

I think found a mistake, and a possible correction, in the postgres documentation regarding explain plans.

From: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/using-explain.html

```
Index Scan using tenk2_unique2 on tenk2 t2  (cost=0.29..7.91 rows=1 width=244) (actual time=0.021..0.022 rows=1 loops=10)
```

"In the above example, we spent a total of **0.220** milliseconds executing the index scans on tenk2."

The docs would seem to indicate `Actual Total Time` * `Actual Loops` = total time spent on an operation.

However, from a JSON plan I produced:

```
 "Plans": [
        {
          "Node Type": "Hash Join",
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Join Type": "Inner",
          "Startup Cost": 66575.34,
          "Total Cost": 76861.82,
          "Plan Rows": 407,
          "Plan Width": 290,
          "Actual Startup Time": 49962.789,
          "Actual Total Time": 51206.643,
          "Actual Rows": 127117,
          "Actual Loops": 3,
          "Output": [ ... ],
...
"Execution Time": 52677.398
```

(The complete plan is [here](https://explain.depesz.com/s/a7lH).)

`Actual Total Time` * `Actual Loops` = 51 sec * 3 = 2 min 33 sec clearly exceeds the `Execution Time` of 52.7 seconds.

Am I understanding the documentation correctly?

If so, shouldn't it say, "we spent a total of **0.01** milliseconds executing the index scans on tenk2"?

Comment: The documentation is correct in this case. Your `EXPLAIN` output is incomplete, so it's hard to make a judgement if it contradicts the documentation or not.

Comment: How can the documentation be correct if `Actual Total Time` * `Actual Loops` exceeds `Execution Time`?

Comment: I'm not sure. That's why I'd like to see the whole plan. If it is not too much to ask, in text format.

Comment: Here it is: http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/plan_1553519907593.  The operation in my post is the hash join using `s._fixation_key = f._fixation_key`.

Comment: That link leads to an empty page for me. Can you add it to the question?

Comment: Sorry, I thought the plan would be visible to others.  It's over 900 lines long, so I'd rather not post it here.  I'll try emailing it to you.  I found an email address for you, and I hope it's the right one.  Thanks for sticking with me, @LaurenzAlbe!

Comment: No. Just [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55329262/edit) and add the information there.

Comment: http://pasted.co/1dc511e3  (It's too large for a SO comment.  SO accepts up to 30k, and the plan is about 45k.)

Comment: Do *not* add a comment, click on the link in my previous comment to edit your own question.

Comment: Ok, I can read it now.

Comment: Most people prefer the plain text output of `explain` not the JSON output (that is intended to be processed by software, not by a human eye)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Hash Join` is underneath a `Gather` node:

```
Gather (cost=67,575.34..77,959.52 rows=977 width=290) (actual time=51,264.085..52,595.474 rows=381,352 loops=1)
Buffers: shared hit=611279 read=99386
  -> Hash Join (cost=66,575.34..76,861.82 rows=407 width=290) (actual time=49,962.789..51,206.643 rows=127,117 loops=3)
     Buffers: shared hit=611279 read=99386
```

That means that The query started two background workers which ran in parallel with the main backend to complete the hash join (see the `"Workers Launched": 2` in the execution plan).

Now it is evident that if three processes work on a task, the total execution time will not be the sum of the individual execution times.

In other words, the rule about multiplication of execution time with the number of loops holds for nested loop join, (which is single threaded), but not for parallel execution of a query.

Comment: Your answer has led me to read the explain and parallel query docs much more closely.